# Taiga+GitLab integration: only enable for master branch?

Tags: git, gitlab, webhooks, taiga

At work we use GitLab and Taiga.

So we enabled the integration between them, and now when a developer pushes a commit that includes the text `TG-XYZ #closed` then the taiga issue with number XYZ gets closed and a comment is placed in it auomatically.

This is definitely great. However, it doesn't work well with MergeRequests (or feature branches in general): as we don't want to close the taiga issue until the MergeRequest is merged to master.

How to restrict this integration to only work with the master branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've found a workaround that is good enough: create MergeRequests only from forks of the repository instead of from branches in the repository.

If you want to enforce this policy so that your devs don't break it by mistake, you can go use the "Protect branches" feature in gitlab and use a wildcard (*) to not allow any creation of new branches (this way they will be able to push branches on each developer's fork, and so the notifications to Taiga will only arrive when the MR is merged to master).

Comment: Good workaround, and more precise than my answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

For commits which need to go through a merge request approval workflow, you could consider:

- *not* using #closed (in order to not close the Taiga tocket too soon)
- set up a [Merge REquest event webhook](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/web_hooks/web_hooks.md#merge-request-events), which will call a listener of your own: that listener would, when detecting a close event, read the commit message and call [Taiga REST API](https://taigaio.github.io/taiga-doc/dist/api.html) itself in order to close the corresponding issue ([issue status edit api](https://taigaio.github.io/taiga-doc/dist/api.html#issue-statuses-edit)).

Comment: but not all commits go through a MR, we want the commits that go directly to master branch to still use the hook

Comment: @knocte as long as they are pushed directly on master, then they can keep their commit message and benefit from Taiga status changes described in https://tree.taiga.io/support/integrations/changing-elements-status-via-commit-message/

Comment: but if I enable that integration, the commits pushed to the branches (for the MergeRequests) will close the issues too... or are you recommending to do that only for the commits directly committed to the master branch, and then use the MergeRequest-event-webhook to just grab the TG number and close it from my listener?

Comment: @knocte yes that is the idea. For commits pushed to the branches for merge request, I would not use the Taiga native integration, but manage it directly from the webhook.

Comment: it's a kinda tricky workflow, wish I could configure the original webhook to ignore pushes to non-master

Comment: @knocte I agree. Do you have access to the source of the GitLab Taiga integration webhook?

Comment: both are opensource projects, so I hope yes